# shell script calling ansible play book

Tags: shell, groovy, ansible, ansible-2.x

My jenkins job written in groovy calls a shell script which internally calls ansible playbook for sns publishing and route53 mapping. I want to handle the ansible script failures in a manner that it propogates to the jenkins the shell script and then the groovy jenkins job. 
Can you pls let me know if there is a way where I can throw the ansible error to shell script and propogate to jenkins groovy code.
Any help will be appreciated

```
ansible-playbook -vvv -c local "route53Mapping.yml" --extra-vars '{"hostedZoneId":'${hostedZoneId}', "route53Url":'${route53Url}'}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `ansible.cfg` if it does not exist yet in your ansible project

Add the following instruction to it to create a local log file

```
log_path = ./ansible-playbook.log
```

When the playbook fails, it exits when an shell exit code different than `0`, so you can for instance display the last n lines of the file `ansible-playbook.log` or even better redirect the content of the file to stderr from your script